Почему VSCode не видит загруженных в окружение библиотек и модулей?
Помогите пожалуйста, устранить ошибку.
После загрузки в среду face_recognition_models, в терминале возникает ошибка Please install face_recognition_models with this command before using face_recognition:
pip install git+https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition_models
Вывела в терминал список установленных библиотек и моделей Package                 Version

click                   8.1.7
colorama                0.4.6
dlib                    19.24.4
face-recognition        1.3.0
face_recognition_models 0.3.0
numpy                   2.0.0
opencv-python           4.10.0.84
pillow                  10.3.0
pip                     24.1
После этого запустила код, возникла ошибка
Please install face_recognition_models with this command before using face_recognition:
pip install git+https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition_models

Так, а пробовали в итоге устанавливать той командой, которую пишет (pip install git+https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition_models)? Запускаете как, из активированного окружения в терминале или через запуск в самом vscode?

И какое окружение выбрано в собственно VSC?

пробовала установить той командой, которую пишет в терминале. запускала через терминал в VSCode, в активированном окружении, выдает ту же ошибку и предлагает воспользоваться той же командой. Получается замкнутый круг.
